# How to use data dictionary on creating physical file for DB2 for IBM i (as400)

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, data-dictionary

Can someone help me on creating a physical file where the reference field is placed in a data dictionary. how to code it in a physical file in order to link with the data dictionary. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a specific reason, most notably to maintain compatibility with the System/36 while operating in the S/36 Execution Environment, there hopefully will be no cause to use a Data Dictionary (*DTADCT) object on any system running with the IBM i OS.  Their use is deprecated; database files should be created with SQL Data Definition Language (DDL), or if necessary per some other [mostly for compatibility] issues, then perhaps instead created using Data Definition Specifications (DDS).  That said...
A Physical Database File (PF) can be created directly from the definitions in a Data Dictionary (*DTADCT) object using the option 1=Create taken from the **Work with Database Files** panel presented by the invocation of the *Work With DB Files Using IDDU* (WRKDBFIDD) command.  The file that is created will be linked, implicitly, to the File Definition; i.e. there is no requirement to effect the Link Data Definition (LNKDTADFN) after creating a Program Described Database File with for example either of the Build File (BLDFILE) OCL command or the Create Physical File (CRTPF) command including a Record Length (RCDLEN) specification.  Note: The 1=Create will attempt always to create an Externally Described file, such that the value for maintaining the *link* is somewhat debased.
To define and create the File Definition that specifies the Record Format Definition(s) that choose which field(s) to include would be effected using the Interactive Data Definition Utility (IDDU), as already mentioned by Charles.  From the aforementioned interface [WRKDBFIDD], there is the F21=*Work With Definitions* to get access to the definitions stored in the Data Dictionary; or from a command-line, the request to get to the same place, is via the *Work With Data Definitions* (WRKDTADFN) command.
There is a IDDU User's Guide:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/rzatc/sc415704.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Way back on the System/36, there was a utility known as Interactive Data Definition Utility (IDDU) which stored field definitions in a data dictionary.

This utility was brought forward onto the AS/400.  You could use the Create Data Dictionary (CRTDDTADCT) command to create the data dictionary for IDDU to use.

Apparently the command is still supported, even on today's POWER systems running IBM i.  [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/crtdtadct.htm?lang=en)

However, I've been on the platform since 1996, and I've never seen or heard of it being used.  IDDU had limitations on the original AS/400, let alone on today's systems.

Instead, the standard practice is to create a "field reference file" using either DDS or SQL DDL.  Obviously, SQL DDL is preferred as many newer features in the DB can only be used with SQL defined tables.

A field reference file/table is simply just like any other file/table.  Except you don't use it to store data, you only use it when defining another file/table.

```
create table MY_DATA_DICT (
  name char(50) not null with default
  address char(50) not null with default
  ...
)
```

then you can use it

```
create table CUSTOMERS 
  (name, address_1, address_2)
  as (select name, address, address
        from MY_DATA_DICT
     )
  with no data
  --below are some copy option you may or may not want
  including column defaults
  including identity column attributes
  including implicitly hidden
  including row change timestamp
```